# Special characters in UTF-8 using RenderBody()

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing site in ASP.NET MVC6 with Polish letters. They work just fine when I write them in _Layout.cshtml, but I'm also using RenderBody() for rendering views.

Using Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) inside view, displays Polish characters properly, but when I use plain html and write something, all I see on the website is "?" in place of every used Polish letter.

In _layout.cshtml I have a declaration:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And in web.config I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Hello, did you resolve the issue? I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with asp.net core aka MVC6, visual studio 2017. Especial characters like â appear �  and client side validation like ViewBag.Equals("â") is not working properly.

So I change the view files (.cshtml ) codification with notepad++  from  ANSI to UTF-8.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I checked my global solution settings for UTF-8, but I didn't checked single file encoding setting, so in solution explorer you have to click your .cshtml file, then:

> file->advanced safe options->Unicode(UTF-8 with signature)-Codepage 65001

Now it works.